# installing qt application in a different folder

Tags: qt, qmake

I would like to install to a qt application to `INSTALL_ROOT`.
Currently the destination is hard coded the  `pro` file under `target.path`, but I would like to get the destination when running:

```
make install INSTALL_ROOT=/root/parts/myapp/install
```

**how can I access `make install`'s command line arguments from qt's `.pro` script?**

Comment: Your question seems backwards. The `make install ` command is only executed after the .pro file has already been parsed by qmake. `INSTALL_ROOT` would have to be present on the qmake command line or in an environment variable.

Comment: can't I access the command line arguments of the make install from within the .pro file (e.g. $1)?

Comment: You're still thinking backwards. When you call `qmake`, it reads your .pro file and generates a `Makefile`. Then when you call `make`, and `make install`, it only looks at that Makefile, not your .pro file. You can add code in .pro file that will be passed down to `make install`, but you cannot pass arguments to `make install` that will be passed to .pro file.

Comment: `$${VAR}`  is qmake variable; `$$(VAR)` is **qmake**'s environment vaiable; `$(VAR)` is **make**'s environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the INSTALL_ROOT variable seems to work for me. If I set target.path to /usr/local/bin I get this into the resulting Makefile from qmake:

```
$(QINSTALL_PROGRAM) $(QMAKE_TARGET) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/local/bin/$(QMAKE_TARGET)
```

It seems INSTALL_ROOT is prepended to target.path. So I tested with a sample app like this:

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    return printf("HELLO!\n") > 0;
}
```

test.pro

```
QT += core
SOURCES += main.cpp
target.path = /
INSTALLS += target
```

then:

```
$ qmake

$ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o test main.o   /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so -lGL -lpthread

$ INSTALL_ROOT="$PWD/out" make install
/usr/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe test /home/luca/tmp/test/out/test
strip /home/luca/tmp/test/out/test

$ ./out/test 
HELLO!
```